# Having problems trying to convert a json to a DataFrame

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem

1.Create a function 'wbURL' that takes an indicator, a country code, and begin and end years to creates a URL of the following format：
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/COUNTRYCODE/indicators/INDICATORformat=json&date=BEGIN_DATE:END_DATE

2. Create another function 'wbDF' that takes the same inputs and returns a dataframe constructed from the response (the response will come as a JSON list, and the 1st (i.e., index 1) element of this list contains the relevant data. Extract this element, which is a list of dictionaries---this is what you want to construct the dataframe out of.Drop all columns except indicator country date and value. For the country and value columns, notice that the data is itself a dictionary: use apply to extract the value out of these dictionaries.

This is the code I wrote out:

```py
def wbURL(contcode, ind, begin, end):
    return f'http://api.worldbank.org/countries{contcode}/indicators/{ind}?format=json&date={begin}:{end}'

def wbDF(contcode, ind, begin, end):
    url = wbURL(contcode, ind, begin, end)
    response = requests.get(url)
    wb_raw = response.content
    wb = json.loads(wb_raw)
    data = wb[1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.drop(columns=['countryiso3code', 'unit', 'obs_status', 'decimal'])
    df['indicator'] = [d['id'] for d in [d['indicator'] for d in data]]
    df['country'] = [d['value'] for d in [d['country'] for d in data]]
    df['date'] = [d['date'] for d in data]
    df['value'] = [d['value'] for d in data]
    return df

test = wbDF('GBR', 'SP.DYN.LE00.IN', 2000, 2019)
print(test)
```

When I ren it, i got an error:

IndexError: list index out of range

I would like someone to have a look at the code I have written and give me some advice on how I should change it to make ir working

Comment: "the 1st (i.e., index `1`) element" -> you mean index `0` ? (if your data only has one element, then the index out of range error is likely from there)   |    Your code is not indented, it's not very readable, could you edit the post ?

Comment: for JSON to Dataframe, you should use `pandas.read_json` which is described here:   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html